# how to hide header and footer on scroll in android

Tags: android, scroll, header, hide, footer

there is two LinearLayouts header and footer in main activity

also RecyclerView inside swipeRefreshLayout between them

now i want to hide header and footer with use LayoutParam, but it shows gap after changing layoutParam and swipeRefreshLayout's height doesn't changes.

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have try to solve your problem use the demo.

the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="click"
        android:background="#fffe4a" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#3489ff" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#fffe4a" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the java file.

```
package com.example.wangze.instantdemo1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void click(View view){
        View view_bottom = findViewById(R.id.view_bottom);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view_bottom.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = 20;
        view_bottom.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

When i click the top view. The bottom is smaller,and not have gap. Maybe it can help you.